# Questions about salting passwords

Tags: php, mysql, hash, salt

Okay. Say for example that i set the salt for a password to "hello." Can't someone just look at the source code and discover the salt? If so, how would I hide it? Thanks.

Comment: Do you _need_ to share your source code with people you don't trust?

Comment: Remember, if they can see you code, your site has already been compromised. They probably have access to your database as well. You're no longer protecting your application, but protecting passwords of your users (who in majority use one password on all websites they use)

Comment: @SRM: All (string) hashes have collisions.

Comment: @SRM: And the fact is that all hashes that hash to a finite number of bits *will* have collisions. The fact that there are an infinite possible number of inputs, mapping to a finite number of outputs, *guarantees* that there are two inputs that will give the same output.

Comment: @Anon Alright, alright.  I concede.  You are correct and my statement was wrong.  I've removed them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Salts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) are are usually stored in plain text alongside the password hash. The main reason they are there is to make it more difficult to use precomputed [rainbow tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) and more difficult to perform a [dictionary attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_attack) on all the passwords in the database.

You should also use a *different* randomly generated salt for each password, rather than a single salt for your entire application. This means that each password must be cracked separately.

Comment: Which is also why they should be longer than 5 characters, and consist of some non-letter characters. Having a separate salt for each user also helps.

Comment: @Mchl: Salts *should* be unique per-user. The whole point of a salt is so that an attacker needs to attack each hash individually, instead of computing one lot of rainbow tables and running it against your whole user database. Using a site-wide salt is probably even *worse* than not using one, because then you think you have some security when really you don't.

Answer (score 5):

First of all: **Security is HARD**. Don't try and do it yourself, because you *will* screw it up. Use a well-established library to handle user authentication.

Secondly, you seem to misunderstand the purpose of a salt. The salt is just there to prevent easy reversing of password hashes - there should be a unique salt for each user, but it's fine to store the salt in the same place as the hashed password.

Answer (score 3):

Salts are best when they are dynamic (say the member's join date).  Even if the attacker *knows* the way you compute the hash, they have to brute force **each** salted and hashed password -- which takes a lot of time, for (in general) little reward.

That being said, if the attacker is looking at your code server-side, you already have a *much* larger problem.

Answer (score 1):

1) Don't use the same salt for multiple accounts. If you can't show your source-code and trust that your passwords are still secure, you've done it wrong.

2) **[PKCS #5 v2.1, section 4](ftp://ftp.rsasecurity.com/pub/pkcs/pkcs-5v2/pkcs5v2_1.pdf)**

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, your "source code" is running on a web server, and not on the client side (javascript) where anybody can see it.